# Simple AJAX library in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've created two simple methods: one to instantiate a new `XMLHttpRequest` object and open the request and another to handle the request.

Can you please point out improvements that can be made or any shortcomings in my code?

```
ajax: function(opts) {

  var xhr, method, body, constructor;

  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  method = opts.body ? 'POST' : opts.method ? opts.method.toUpperCase() : 'GET';

  if(opts.body) {
    constructor = opts.body.constructor;
    if(constructor === Object || constructor === String) {
      body = opts.body;
    }
  }

  this.ajaxComplete.call(xhr, opts);

  xhr.open(method, opts.url, (opts.async === undefined ? true : false));

  // Set the default request headers
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  if(opts.headers) {
    for(var prop in opts.headers) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(prop, opts.headers[prop]);
    }
  }

  xhr.send(body || null);
},

ajaxComplete: function(opts) {
  var that = this,
      data, complete;

  that.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(that.readyState == 4) {
      if(that.status == 200) {
        data = (that.responseXML || that.responseText);
        opts.success.call(that, data);
      }
      else {
        data = (that.responseXML || that.responseText);
        opts.error.call(opts, data, that.statusText, that.status);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your code work? `constructor===Object` seems fishy

Answer (score 2):

As [Dan Pantry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42325/dan-pantry) pointed out, `=== Object` and `=== String` do not work; you'll have to compare with a string name of the object:

```
if(opts.body) {
  constructor = opts.body.constructor;
  if(typeof constructor === "object" || typeof constructor === "string") {
    body = opts.body;
  }
}
```

---

Not every browser supports the `XMLHttpRequest` object. You'll have to do a little checking to get the right object.

The two main objects used are `XMLHttpRequest` and `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`. The second one is used by `IE`.

You can use a simple ternary to see which object to use:

```
xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
```

---

If you need to copy `this` into a variable, most people use `self`, not `that`.

---

I don't think you need to check whether to return `that.responseXML` or `that.responseText`; I think `responseText` will contain the response no matter what, so you should just use that.

---

The `complete` variable is un-used in the `ajaxComplete` function; you don't need it.

---

You should put parenthesis around some places when defining the `method` variable. It is quite difficult to understand being that there is more than one ternary.

---

For one-time-use variables like `data`, don't store them in a variable; just substitue the value of the variable where you are using the variable and destroy the variable.

It's a waste of memory to keep something in memory that you only use once.

Comment: Are you sure you aren’t mixing up `constructor` with `typeof`? `typeof` most certainly does return strings, but `constructor` will be a function, like `String`.

Comment: Also, `XMLHttpRequest ? /* … */ : /* … */` will fail with a `ReferenceError` if `XMLHttpRequest` doesn’t exist—you’ll need to use `window.XMLHttpRequest` in the condition instead.